# Terraform issue with Keyvault access

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

So I defined the kayvault definition in terraofrm and now looking to provide access to an AD group by the below definition, but I get error as

> Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding
> to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
> returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequestFormat" Message="The
> request was incorrectly formatted."

here is the definition :

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vault_access" {
  scope              = azurerm_key_vault.vault.id
  role_definition_id = "Contributor"
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.access_audit_members.object_id
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Terraform issue with Keyvault access

```hs
role_definition_id = "Contributor"
```

As you have used `role_definition_id` instead of `role_definition_name` in your code, please make sure to provide the correct `Role Definition ID` instead of the role name.

Here is the updated code to assign the role to the `Key Vault` at the `Azure AD Group` scope

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "srikv12"
  resource_group_name = "Sri"
}
data "azuread_group" "Adgroup" {
  display_name     = "keyvaultgroup"
  security_enabled = true
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.Adgroup.object_id
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once the above code is executed, the `Contributor` role will be assigned to the `Key Vault` at the `Azure AD` scope

[image]

Refer the `registry.terraform` for more details about [`resource "azurerm_role_assignment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment) block.